# We are going to eat- after eat, must be a noun?

Tags: sentence-construction, transitivity

"**We are going to eat.**" I told my son.

Is the sentence above a complete sentence?

After eat, must be a noun?

Comment: No. The verb *eat* is both transitive and intransitive, and can stand with or without a direct object. I would have thought that was the case in most European languages - it is certainly so in French. What is your language?

Comment: @WS2 I think it depends on the context; in many cases the context is totally obvious that you're talking about food. Thus, you can use a transitive verb without any object. In other word, the object will be implied.

Comment: @Cardinal Isn't that the case with most action verbs that can be used intransitively. *After dinner Jane will sing*. Clearly she is going to sing something.

Comment: @WS2 I just said that  as a complement to yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Eat* doesn't have to take an object, but the meaning changes slightly when it doesn't have one.  Many verbs in English have slightly different meanings with and without objects.

*Eat* without an object means to have lunch, dinner, or other meal that makes sense according to the time or context.